# What are the rules about self-modifying parse rules in Rebol/Red?

Tags: parsing, rebol, red

I am looking at self-modifying rules and wondering what exactly the semantics are and how they would work at all.  That's a pretty broad question, but I'll use a specific "how would I do this" to turn it into a more focused one.  *(^(64) being the hex ascii for lowercase "d" so it doesn't get found)*

```
rule: ["a" "b" (insert find rule "^(64)" "c" probe rule) "d" "e"]
parse "abcde" rule
```

If I run that, I get (in both Rebol and Red):

```
["a" "b" (insert find rule "d" "c" probe rule) "c" "d" "e"]
== false
```

The rule seems to have been updated, and it was updated in a fairly "safe-seeming way" (if there is any such thing as safe).  There are more evil versions:

```
rule: ["a" "b" (clear rule probe rule) "d" "e"]
parse "abcde" rule
```

In both Rebol and Red that gets:

```
[]
== false
```

I'm sort of confused how it doesn't crash.  But assuming it's been bulletproofed somehow, is there a way to get the first example to work?

Comment: What about SKIPing the inserted char? rule: ["a" "b" (insert find rule "d" "c" probe rule) skip "d" "e"] ;this returns true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But assuming it's been bulletproofed somehow...

In R3-Alpha it hasn't, and if you are unlucky (such as by causing a series expansion) you can crash by doing this.  See [#2214: "Modifying running PARSE rule leads to execution beyond rule TAIL, possible crash"](https://github.com/rebol/rebol-issues/issues/2214)

So you should *not* modify a rule that is currently being processed by PARSE.  You can--however--modify a nested rule inside a rule if that rule is not running at that moment:

```
 subrule: ["c"]
 rule: ["a" (insert subrule "b") subrule]
 parse "abc" rule
```

This is formalized in the [Ren-C build](https://github.com/metaeducation/ren-c) by locking rules from modification while the parser is traversing them.  Another approach for the parser would be to test the length on each fetch in the rule and abort if it was past the length.  Though that would prevent crashing, this would lead to complex and dodgy behavior--and degrade performance by paying for the check.

*(For similar reasons, in Ren-C you cannot modify a block currently being executed with DO either.  But by modifying a nested parentheses group that isn't running you can accomplish the same workaround as with PARSE above.)*

> ```
> rule: ["a" "b" (clear rule probe rule) "d" "e"]
> parse "abcde" rule
> ```
>
> I'm sort of confused how it doesn't crash.

In Rebol's R3-Alpha, this particular case doesn't crash or complain because it doesn't reclaim the memory in the series *unless it expands and requires a new allocation*.  It merely writes a terminator at the head position of the series (overwriting the "a") and adjusts a cached length.  PARSE ignores the length and only looks for an END marker.  So it kept going until it found the stale old end marker.

To see that, you could have also tried:

```
>> rule: ["a" "b" (clear rule) "c" "d" "e"]
== ["a" "b" (clear rule) "c" "d" "e"]

>> parse "abcde" rule
== true
```

You're basically using values that are in garbage memory.

Comment: If a grammar in Rebol is "self-modifying," then it is essentially an [adaptive grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_grammar).

Answer (score 2):

This works

```
>> rule: ["a" "b"  (insert first find rule block! "c" probe rule ) [] "d" "e"]
== ["a" "b" (insert first find rule block! "c" probe rule) [] "d" "e"]
>> parse "abcde" rule
["a" "b" (insert first find rule block! "c" probe rule) ["c"] "d" "e"]
== true
```

as there are the number of rule elements and the position of the rule cursor at the first level not changed. The second level seems to get loaded just at entry.

This works too

```
>> rule: ["a" "b"   (insert first find rule "d" "c" probe rule )  "d" "e"]
== ["a" "b" (insert first find rule "d" "c" probe rule) "d" "e"]
>> parse "abcde" rule
["a" "b" (insert first find rule "d" "c" probe rule) "cd" "e"]
== true
```

**In a general form of a self modifying rule you use a variant lower level rule you can change or replace as in**

```
sub_rule: []
rule: ["a" "b" (sub_rule: "c" probe rule) sub_rule "d" "e"]

parse "abcde" rule
["a" "b" (sub_rule: "c" probe rule) sub_rule "d" "e"]
 == true
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
>> rule: ["a" "b" m: (insert find rule "^(64)" "c" probe rule) skip "d" "e"]
```

or

```
>> rule: ["a" "b" m: (insert find rule "^(64)" "c" probe rule m: next m) :m "d" "e"]
>> parse "abcde" rule
["a" "b" m: (insert find rule "d" "c" probe rule m: next m) :m "c" "d" "e"]
== true
```